# concatenated PEM file: split private key and certificate chain

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl

I have a .pem file with SSL private key and certificate chain for my web-server concatenated into a single file. The file is in following structure:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
...data...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...data...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...data...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...data...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

What commands I use to split it to have separate files `private.key` and `fullchain.pem`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the input file `your-file.pem` contains only 1 private key and corresponding chain of certificates.

Extract private key:

```
openssl storeutl -keys your-file.pem > private.key
```

Extract fullchain certificates:

```
openssl storeutl -certs your-file.pem > fullchain.pem
```

If the certificate data comes from standard input, use `/dev/stdin` :

```
cat your-file.pem | openssl storeutl -keys /dev/stdin
cat your-file.pem | openssl storeutl -certs /dev/stdin
```

Answer (score 0):

My Cert is password protected so I can input --passin to input password via command-line
`openssl storeutl -passin pass:<my-pass> -keys mycert.pem`

My Certs are printing, but not the ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY, any idea how to get the private key printed?

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----  
-------------------------------------   
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```